# Having trouble creating multiple sprites from one class

Tags: c#, xna, sprites, xna-4.0

So I am trying to make more than one sprite using a single class but I cannot seem to get the sprites to be drawn at all or drawn in different places (they are all just on top of one another).

In my Game1 I have:

```
    Flag flag;
    List<Flag> GameFlags = new List<Flag>();
```

then in LoadContent:

```
flag = new Flag();
tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("FlagTexture");
tempRectangle = new Rectangle(50, 500,tempTexture.Width / 3, tempTexture.Height / 3);
flag.SetSprite(tempTexture);
flag.SetRectangle(tempRectangle);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            GameFlags.Add(flag);
            flag.spriteRectangle.X += 100;
        }
```

Then in Draw:

```
 foreach (Flag flag in GameFlags)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            flag.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
```

The effect I am after is having 2 sprites spaced out by a specified amount of space. Image if the underscores were spacing and the zeros were sprites in the following:

0____________________________0

Any help and advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

TeaBelliedTitch.

Comment: You should move your `spriteBatch.Begin()` and `spriteBatch.End()` calls out of the loop. You only need to call them once in this context. Put begin before the loop and end after.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        GameFlags.Add(flag);
        flag.spriteRectangle.X += 100;
    }
```

Is this not adding a reference to the same object? So you have a list of references to one thing as opposed to a list of things or references to things

Comment: Yes, they are going to want `new Flag()`s at the start of each loop iteration.